# Restoring Geometry in Latex

Tags: geometry

I want that the chapters start on even pages, so I used twoside with open right command but it made the \restoregeometry not work on even pages. Can anybody help me fixing this ?[image: PDF]

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,openright]{report}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\fancyhead[RE]{Section \thesection}
\fancyhead[LE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[RO]{Section \thesection}
\fancyhead[LO]{Chapter \thechapter}


\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}




\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{afterpage,lipsum}


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
 \newgeometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,250mm},
 left=20mm,
 right=10mm,
 top=20mm,
 }


\includegraphics[width = 50mm]{LOGOBourgogne.png}%\\[15ex]
\hspace{6.5cm}\includegraphics[width = 55mm]{Logo.PNG}\\[15ex]
    \centering
    {\scshape\LARGE University of Burgundy \par}
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\Large Final year project\par}
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    {\huge\bfseries  Channel Emulation using SDR\par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\Large\itshape Ali SABRA\par}
    \vfill
    Supervised by\par
    {\large\itshape Pr. Marion BERBINEAU}


    \vfill

{\large \today\par}



%\author{Ali SABRA \\ Supervisor: Marion Berbineau}
%\date{from May to August 2019}

\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you please tell us how do you see that `\restoregeometry` is not working?

Comment: I want to use newgeometry for the titlepage only. So I put \restoregeometry to get back to the old geometry for the rest of the report. But instead, the geometry used for the title page is applied to odd pages as you can see in the image above. I want the layout of page 9 and all odd pages to be as page 10 (and all even pages). Thank you